# Django set cookie for 1 year

Tags: django

I want to set the age of the cookie in my application for 1 year so that users don't have to login everytime they access the application. Is it simply a case of doing the following to make this happen:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 31556952
```

It seems to work fine, but just wanted to make sure I hadn't missed anything out.

Comment: This is usually not a good practice to allow such long cookies unless user checks a "remember me" check-box or something like that. The point is that you should not do that unless user explicitly agreed to.

Comment: Will you still have their session info in the database a year on?

Comment: I agree with miki725. Anyway you can check it yourself. Open list of cookies in your browser and look at expire date of sessionid cookie (firefox: edit->preferences->privacy->"Show cookies").

Comment: @pastylegs yes, he probably will, see [django docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-table)

Comment: @miki725 Thanks for raising the concern the users have agreed to it.

Comment: @pastylegs Good point I hadn't really given that any thought, thinking about it now, I will still have their session info in the database a year on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the expiry date of the cookie in the browser to ensure the intended behaviour.